# Optimize brute force with permutations

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, brute-force

EXPLAINING WHAT THE SCRIPT DOES

I made a python script where the goal is to balance marbles on a circular board. Marble 1 weighs 1 Unit, 2 weighs 2 Units, and so on. The goal is to find the best order so it's a balanced as possible.

PROBLEM

I also made a method that tries all the possibilities with permutations. I get a memory error if I try with more than 10 marbles (3628800 possibilites).

Is there any way to optimize the code with either multi threading/ multiprocessing, maybe a better way than permutations?

CODE
    # balance_game.py
    # A program used to your skills in balancing marbles on a board

```
from itertools import permutations
from math import cos, radians, pow, sin, sqrt
from time import time


# Checks if marbles will balance on a circular board
# Marble 1 weighs 1 unit, 2 weighs 2 units, and so on
def test_your_might(NUMBER_OF_MARBLES, marbles):
    angle = 360 / NUMBER_OF_MARBLES
    angles = [angle * n for n in range(1, NUMBER_OF_MARBLES + 1)]

    X = []
    Y = []
    Fx = []
    Fy = []

    i = 0
    for n in range(0, NUMBER_OF_MARBLES):
        angle = radians(angles[i])
        X.append(cos(angle))
        Y.append(sin(angle))
        i += 1

    for n in range(0, NUMBER_OF_MARBLES):
        Fx.append(X[n] * marbles[n])

    for n in range(0, NUMBER_OF_MARBLES):
        Fy.append(Y[n] * marbles[n])

    return sqrt(pow(sum(Fx), 2) + pow(sum(Fy), 2))


def brute_force_solution(NUMBER_OF_MARBLES):
    possibilities = permutations([x for x in range(1, NUMBER_OF_MARBLES + 1)])
    solutions = {}
    for possibility in possibilities:
        possibility = list(possibility)
        solution = test_your_might(NUMBER_OF_MARBLES, possibility)
        solutions[str(possibility)] = solution
    return solutions


# print(test_your_might(5, [5, 1, 4, 3, 2]))
t0 = time()
solutions = brute_force_solution(10)
t1 = time()

best_order = min(solutions, key=solutions.get)
lowest_score = solutions[best_order]

print(f"Lowest score: {lowest_score}\nOrder: {best_order}")
print(f"It took {t1-t0} seconds to find the best possibility")
print(f"There were {len(solutions)} possibilities")
```

FYI
The method is brute_force_solution

Comment: Is it possible to use the GPU for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the bottleneck is CPU usage, multithreading won't do a lot to help here, but multiprocessing should. Not an expert but have been experimenting with parallelism recently so will have a play around and update this answer if I get anywhere. (EDIT: I have tried a number of attempts at using multiprocessing but I've only succeeded in increasing the run time!)

It might be that you need to store all solutions, but if not, one small optimisation in terms of time, but huge in terms of memory, would be to not store all the possible results and just store the best result, so you're not creating another very long array needlessly. Ideally you could calculate number of solutions directly since it only depends on `NUMBER_OF_MARBLES` but have included it in the function to be consistent.

```
def brute_force_solution(NUMBER_OF_MARBLES):
    possibilities = permutations([x for x in range(1, NUMBER_OF_MARBLES + 1)])
    # count the number of solutions
    number_of_solutions = 0
    best_solution_so_far = None

    for possibility in possibilities:
        number_of_solutions += 1
        possibility = list(possibility)
        solution = test_your_might(NUMBER_OF_MARBLES, possibility)
        # If this solution is the best so far, record the score and configuration of marbles.
        if (best_solution_so_far is None) or (solution < best_solution_so_far[1]):
            best_solution_so_far = (str(possibility), solution)

    # Return the best solution and total number of solutions tested.
    return (best_solution_so_far, number_of_solutions)


t0 = time()
one_solution = brute_force_solution(11)
t1 = time()

best_order = one_solution[0][0]
best_score = one_solution[0][1]
number_of_solutions = one_solution[1]
```

It took a while but it ran with 11 marbles:

```
>>>Lowest score: 0.00021084993450850984
>>>Order: [10, 7, 3, 4, 11, 1, 8, 9, 5, 2, 6]
>>>It took 445.57227993011475 seconds to find the best possibility
>>>There were 39916800 possibilities
```

and was marginally quicker when run for 10 (and note that you aren't including the sorting of your results in your timing which is not needed with this new method and adds almost another second to your time to get the best solution):

Old

```
Lowest score: 1.608181078507726e-17
Order: [1, 7, 3, 10, 4, 6, 2, 8, 5, 9]
It took 43.81806421279907 seconds to find the best possibility
There were 3628800 possibilities
```

New

```
Lowest score: 1.608181078507726e-17
Order: [1, 7, 3, 10, 4, 6, 2, 8, 5, 9]
It took 37.06034016609192 seconds to find the best possibility
There were 3628800 possibilities
```